# Stanford nndep to get parse trees

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

Using Stanford CoreNLP, I am trying to parse text using the neural nets dependency parser. It runs really fast (that's why I want to use this and not the `LexicalizedParser`), and produces high-quality dependency relations. I am also interested in retrieving the parse trees (Penn-tree style) from that too. So, given the GrammaticalStructure, I am getting the root of that (using `root()`), and then trying to print it out using the `toOneLineString()` method. However, `root()` returns the root node of the tree, with an empty/null list of children. I couldn't find anything on this in the instructions or FAQs.

```
 GrammaticalStructure gs = parser.predict(tagged);

  // Print typed dependencies
  System.err.println(gs);

  // get the tree and print it out in the parenthesised form
  TreeGraphNode tree = gs.root();
  System.err.println(tree.toOneLineString());
```

The output of this is:

```
  ROOT-0{CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation=-1, CharacterOffsetEndAnnotation=-1, PartOfSpeechAnnotation=null, TextAnnotation=ROOT}Typed Dependencies: 
  [nsubj(tell-5, I-1), aux(tell-5, can-2), advmod(always-4, almost-3), advmod(tell-5, always-4), root(ROOT-0, tell-5), advmod(use-8, when-6), nsubj(use-8, movies-7), advcl(tell-5, use-8), amod(dinosaurs-10, fake-9), dobj(use-8, dinosaurs-10), punct(tell-5, .-11)]
  ROOT-0
```

How can I get the parse tree too?

Comment: Are you looking for a constituency parse? Or just to see the dependency parse in S-expression (PTB) format?

Comment: A CFG parse, to be exact, similar to the one you get from the lex parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I can use the Shift-Reduce constituency parser made available by Stanford. It's very fast and the results are comparable.